# Practical use or practical usage?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

When should `Practical use` or `practical usage` should be used and what are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

A general principal of language is try the simplest solution first, and only when that fails try a more complex solution. Simpler word forms also tend to (or as a result) have wider usage than more complex forms.

'Use' tends to describe the normal passage of an action, so we might say that a hammer is of practical use. It is 'useful', or 'full of use'.

'Usage' tends to describe where the use applies, and as such finds great use in language description. So we might say that we find practical usage of the word 'usage' in describing word use.

Comment: sorry but I did not understand the usage part...